# Is "it's been" correct here?

Tags: tense, idiomatic-language, conversation

A: Rough day?

B: No, it's been fine.

A: OK.

B: You?

A: Fine. It's just been long.

1) This conversation is close to midnight, so the day is almost over. In that case is "it's been" natural?

2) Does "it's just been long" seem weird here without adding something to it or is it OK?

3) Is the whole coversation correct and natural?

Comment: It's okay, but you might want to spice it up by having A respond with "Fine, but it's dragging on"

Comment: It’s fine grammatically, but repetition is *generally* to be avoided in dialogue unless it’s used to make a point,